# box shadow to left and right side

Tags: css, box-shadow

I want to add box shadow to left and right side of a div , here I am attaching a image for that, I don't know how to do this, can somebody help me please? please notice that shadow should be to the point mark on left and right.[image]

Comment: you are looking for the `box-shadow` CSS property. You can set more than 1 box shadow by butting a comma between them.

Answer (score 3):

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

.boxWrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0 60px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -20px;
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
  left: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: -40px 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -20px;
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  right: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 40px 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="boxWrapper">
  <div class="box">
    box
  </div>
</div>
```

So this is definitely a neat question. I've played around and was able to at least come up with a stepping stone to the right solution. I've been doing it with the box-shadow method that has been mentioned, but have added it to both an `:after` and `:before` pseudo-selector.

Then, I've rotated both these selectors 8 degrees (just to mimic your provided image) and found that it was still showing some unwanted shadow both above the element and below the element.

To solve that, I wrapped the box with a box wrapper thats sole purpose was to define the size of the box as well as hide anything overflowing on the tops and bottoms.

It will definitely need to be adapted to how you need it, as it kinda feels hacky. But I think this provides some ideas on how to approach the problem.

I've created a Codepen so you can see it at work.
http://codepen.io/RyanAaronGreen/pen/Kagdad

Comment: I had fiddled with the `::before` and `::after` selectors as well, it really is a very neat question. That being said if I was OP I'd probably select your answer.

Comment: @phpLover - did you ever get your answer to this one? I keep coming across this problem when looking back at my previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this gets you what you need. The documentation for the `box-shadow` property is located [Here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.content {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but my requirement is different...please look at this image closely

Comment: explain to me how it is different, also please note that I am _very_ colorblind so the more specific you are the better.

Comment: ok..actually shadow should be on left and right side only .I have mark a point on both side, up to that point i need shadow from bottom and also  shadow starts from near about 10% from bottom.

Comment: Please remember this is a very general case. Open up the code snippet and feel free to fiddle with the values. Also look up the documentation that I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this samples
[CSS3 drop shadow](http://www.bypeople.com/css3-drop-shadow/)